# Union between sets: notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, education

I read in a not recent book, whose name I cannot remember, that instead of using the notation $A\cup B$ to denote the union of sets, the notation $A+B$ was used. Now is $A+B$ always used? If yes I wished to know what is the name of such a sum and what is the current definition with some very simple examples that I can show to my 14-year-old students (first year science high school).

Comment: I would think that notation risked being confused with [Minkowski addition](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) which is a very different concept.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for your link. I not knew this notation. $A+B$ is it always the  Minkowski addition?

Comment: @Sebastiano $A+B$ is certainly not always Minkowski addition, for example certainly not when $a+b$ is not defined for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$

Comment: The notations $AB$ for intersection of sets and $A+B$ for union of sets was common before perhaps 1950.

Comment: @GEdgar I however have read this fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set theoretically,

$$A \cup B:=\{x: \text{$x \in A$ or $x \in B$}\},$$

I.e., the set of points that are in $A$ or $B$ or both.

While

$$A+B:=\{a+b: a \in A, b \in B\}.$$

I.e., the set of sums of elements from $A$ together with elements of $B$.

Hope this helps!!

For example, if $\Bbb{I}$ denotes the irrationals, then

$$\Bbb{I} \cup \Bbb{Q}=\Bbb{R}$$

But

$$\Bbb{I}+\Bbb{Q}=\{a+b: a \in \Bbb{I}, b \in \Bbb{Q}\}.$$

Which is not all of $\Bbb{R}$. Namely, $a+b \in \Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Q}$ where $a \in \Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Q}, b \in \Bbb{Q}$. This is a known fact which requires some proof of course.

Also a note, or remark on notation, $A-B$ could means elements in $A$ but not in $B$ or set of differences ($\{a-b:a \in A,b \in B\}$), which is why i write set of elements in $A$ but not in $B$ as $A \setminus B$. Please upvote if you agree with everything I've said! :) cheers to more maths!

Comment: What is the difference with an example?

Comment: @Sebastiano here ill add an example.

Comment: @Sebastiano answer your question? The example I mean.

Comment: in the sense that if an element of $A$ is 1 and an element of $B$ is 3 then $a+b=4$ which has nothing to do with the union of elements.

Comment: @Sebastiano yes

Comment: @Sebastiano precisely, $A+B$ is a set of sums, while $A \cup B$ is points in either or.

Comment: @Sebastiano read my last edit made. its a notational thing.